# Proper way for json parsing for mutable structure with gson

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, android-viewmodel

I'm getting response from server based on such structure:

```
{
    "success":true,
    "data":{"can be some kind of data, array or error message"}
}
```

What is the right way to map properly data attribute in such situations? 
My attempts was to use Any type and cast after to specified type:

```
data class GeneralResponseModel(
    val success: Boolean,
    val data: Any
)
```

**Provider**

```
//
val response = gson.fromJson(it[0].toString(), GeneralResponseModel::class.java)
//
```

**ViewModel**

```
////////
if (res.success) {
    isLoading.postValue(false)
    ///////
} else {
    val result = res.data as ResponseError
    errorMessage.postValue(ErrorWrapper(ErrorType.REQUEST_ERROR,result.detail,result.title))
    isLoading.postValue(false)
}
///////////
```

And I got

> io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException:
>   com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to
>   com.myapp.model.response.ResponseError

Another attempt was in using empty interface which was implemented by all possible response types. In this situation I got

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for
>   interface com.myapp.model.response.Response.
>   Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this
>   problem.

I'm not sure about proper way to handle such trivial case. Any links, code examples or help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Thanks to Niklas I reconsidered gson into such structure:

```
 lateinit var gson: Gson
        when (methodName) {
            RequestList.LOGIN.methodName -> {
                gson =
                    GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(
                        GeneralResponseModel::class.java,
                        object : JsonDeserializer<GeneralResponseModel> {
                            override fun deserialize(
                                json: JsonElement?,
                                typeOfT: Type?,
                                context: JsonDeserializationContext?
                            ): GeneralResponseModel {
                                val gsonInner = Gson()
                                val jsonObject: JsonObject = json!!.asJsonObject
                                lateinit var generalResponseModel: GeneralResponseModel
                                generalResponseModel = if (!jsonObject.get("success").asBoolean) {

                                    GeneralResponseModel(
                                        false,
                                        gsonInner.fromJson(jsonObject.get("data"), ResponseError::class.java)
                                    )
                                } else {

                                    GeneralResponseModel(
                                        true,
                                        gsonInner.fromJson(jsonObject.get("data"), DriverData::class.java)
                                    )
                                }
                                return generalResponseModel
                            }

                        }).create()
            }
            RequestList.GET_JOBS.methodName -> {
                gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(
                    GeneralResponseModel::class.java,
                    object : JsonDeserializer<GeneralResponseModel> {
                        override fun deserialize(
                            json: JsonElement?,
                            typeOfT: Type?,
                            context: JsonDeserializationContext?
                        ): GeneralResponseModel {
                            val gsonInner = Gson()
                            val jsonObject: JsonObject = json!!.asJsonObject
                            lateinit var generalResponseModel: GeneralResponseModel
                            generalResponseModel = if (!jsonObject.get("success").asBoolean) {

                                GeneralResponseModel(
                                    false,
                                    gsonInner.fromJson(jsonObject.get("data"), ResponseError::class.java)
                                )
                            } else {

                                GeneralResponseModel(
                                    true,
                                    gsonInner.fromJson(jsonObject.get("data"), Array<JobResponse>::class.java)
                                )
                            }
                            return generalResponseModel
                        }

                    }).create()
            }
            else -> gson = Gson()
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is very generic, it can't really be parsed in a type-safe way. Gson can't infer types based on pure text (in your specific case there is nothing telling Gson that your data is a ResponseError).

I would consider a general wrapper class like yours, and then using a [GSON TypeAdapter](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeAdapter-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.Object-) to parse the response to your general wrapper.

You have to instantiate GSON with a Builder to define a custom TypeAdapter.

`registerTypeAdapter(Type type, Object typeAdapter)`
*Configures Gson for custom serialization or deserialization.*

Your wrapper:

```
public class Response<T> {
    T data;
    String message;

    public Response(T data, String message) {
        this.data = data;
        this.message = message;
    }

    boolean hasData() {
        return data != null;
    }

    T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

}
```

Initialization:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
b.registerTypeAdapter(Response.class, new JsonDeserializer<Response>() {
    @Override
    public Response deserialize(JsonElement arg0, Type arg1,
        JsonDeserializationContext arg2) throws JsonParseException {
    // ... create Response object here
    return response;
}
```